# JavaScript Discord.js, not able to send message from inside a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get the discord bot to send me a message inside a if, but I can't get that to work.
I know the if triggers since I get a activation from console.log('inside if');. And I know that
directMessage outside the function works, since I can get the bot to send "Hello from main".
Have also tried adding in the code from directMessage into the if, but no luck with that. Have searched for answers but found no solution.

```
function symPriceChecker(){
    sellStock.forEach(entry => {
      if (parseInt(entry.Price) < symPrice){            
            directMessage(client, 'Hello from if',ID); // But here it does not work
            console.log('inside if');
            sellStock.pop(entry);
            
        }
    });
    repeater2 = setTimeout(symPriceChecker, 5000);   
};

directMessage(client, 'Hello from main',ID); //This one works

// how directMessage looks
module.exports=(client, message, dicsordUser)=>
{
    client.on('ready',()=>{
        client.users.fetch(dicsordUser).then((user) =>{ 
        user.send(message)})})
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const directMessage = async(client, message, dicsordUser) => {
const user = await client.users.fetch(discordUser).catch(() => {});
if (!user) return console.log('no user found');
user.send(message);
}

function symPriceChecker(){
    sellStock.forEach(entry => {
      if (parseInt(entry.Price) < symPrice){            
            directMessage(client, 'Hello from if',ID); // But here it does not work
            console.log('inside if');
            sellStock.pop(entry);
            
        }
    });
    repeater2 = setTimeout(symPriceChecker, 5000);   
};
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, needed to also add async after the first = also

Comment: @Andreas yea i forgot the async